# Srollviewer doesn't work in TabControl.ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, scroll

I have a grid with a tab control inside. My goal is to have a list of tabs on the left of screen, which can be scrolled (There is around 10 tabs in typical scenario). I cannot however make it scroll.

What I tried (from other answers here) and didn't work:

1. Put Height/MaxHeight on my Panels, Grid
2. Wrapping the whole thing in another panel
3. Putting my Panel inside ScrollViewer - can't do that since I cannot put something that isn't panel on top of visual tree in ItemsPanelTemplate
4. Putting the ScrollViewer inside

The base code for the UserControl is here:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:StringToByteArrayConverter x:Key="StringToByteArrayConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
            <DockPanel Background="{StaticResource LightGreyBrush}">
                <Image
                    Width="210"
                    Height="240"
                    DataContext="{Binding DataContext.MyPageModel.MyGraphics.Groups[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Source="{Binding Graphic, Converter={StaticResource StringToByteArrayConverter}}" />
                <Label
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{Binding Name}"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="300" MaxHeight="510" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <TabControl
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyPageModel.MyList.Groups}"
                TabStripPlacement="Left">
                <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel
                            CanVerticallyScroll="True"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemsPanel>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
```

**How can I make the tab list scrollable here?**

Edit: this is visualization of what I want (roughly, paint skills not good):

[image]

Comment: Not without changing to a different control or a bunch of work. A tab control shows precisely ONE tab at a time. There are no other tab items in the control to scroll through. Just the one. Maybe this should be a listbox instead of a tabcontrol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom `ControlTemplate` where you put a `ScrollViewer` around the `TabPanel`.

You will also have to change the `Height` of the first `RowDefinition` in your `Grid` from `Auto` to `*`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="300" MaxHeight="510" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <TabControl
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding MyPageModel.MyList.Groups}"
                TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Border x:Name="contentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,0,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="contentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="headerPanel" Value="0,2,2,2"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TabControl.Template>
            <TabControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel
                            CanVerticallyScroll="True"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="False"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemsPanel>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just... wow. Works flawlessly, thanks. Never would write that myself.